# Not able to clicked on item

Tags: iphone

I have facing very strange issue. I m opeing the default contact form my app. but sometimes i m not able to clicked or select the particular contact from it, but able to scroll it. anybody can give to solution ?

Comment: You are going to have to provide way more information and code if you want any chance of someone helping you.

Comment: Don't clear your problem. Could you provide more detail.. and code if possible?

Comment: I m just calling webserview in background in appDel, But sometime in very rare case, whole is working properly, even i m have to scroll all contact, but not able to select anything. This thing also happn in tableview also. not able to provide u code. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the delgate methods for ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate ?

I am guessing you did not set the delegate of ABPeoplePickerNavigationController  to self and then implement the delegate methods to select a contact

Comment: all the delegate are set perfactly, but not able to selected any contact. Even not able to select row of table also. Its really a very very strange issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding your table view on any other UIView or UIImageView then you have to set the userInteraction True for them so it'll allow the touch on your table view.